# Combine - merge 2 publishers into a single publisher that returns a value when either underlying publisher emits a value

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, combine

I have 2 publishers that return the same type of value. One publisher is meant to emit N/W responses and other is meant to emit cached responses. These publishers will be shared across multiple requests by different consumers.

I am emitting value on them from different code paths. And I am trying to merge these 2 upstream publishers into a single publisher that will return value from either of the 2, to a downstream consumer.

I tried using `MergeMany` but it did not work for me. Publisher1 was sending value but Publisher2 was not sending values. So the downstream sink did not fire.

I tried using `CombineLatest`. But that did not work as 1. It returns a tuple like (Response, Response) instead of just Response 2. It again waits for both to return some value. I can't use `Zip` for the same reasons.

I saw `switchToLatest()` which sounds promising, but I could not find a way to use it on a list of Publishers.

Edit:

I also tried this and had similar result as `MergeMany`

```
return networkPublisher
//    .merge(with: cachedPublisher) // If this is uncommented then the network publisher does not process all the network responses for some reason. 
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the example in your own answer should actually work without `subscribe(on:)` and `receive(on:)`. Why this doesn't happen? Because your implementation is most likely not thread safe. I think, that is your main problem. Also please note, that `subscribe(on:)` set a scheduler for up- AND downstream. This means that `receive(on:)` is unnecessary in your example.

Below are two variants for merging two publishers:

```
let subscription = publisher1.merge(with: publisher2)
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        // your logic
})
```

OR

```
let subscription = Publishers.Merge(publisher1, publisher2)
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        // your logic
})
```

Hopefully I could help you.

Comment: My downstream consumer can sink from a different thread. I think this is the reason why the `.subscribe(on:)` is needed.

Comment: No. If your downstream consumer intentionally changes schedule using `receive(on: )` (or even `subscribe(on:)`), then you have no control over it.

Answer (score -1):

All I had to add was a `receive` and `subscribe` to the chain:

```
return networkPublisher
    .merge(with: cachedPublisher) 
    .receive(on: dispatchQueue)
    .subscribe(on: dispatchQueue)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```